# Android First In First Out Lazyloading

Tags: android, lazy-loading, fifo

Refering to the lazyloading method at http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip, discussed at [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) by Fedor

I would like to know whether the following code can be changed from Last In First Out (LIFO) to First In First Out (FIFO) when displaying images downloaded from web

public class ImageLoader {

```
//the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

private File cacheDir;

public ImageLoader(Context context){


    photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"More");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
{

    if(cache.containsKey(url))
    {           
        imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
    }
    else
    {           
        queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);     
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }    
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
{
    //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
    photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);

        photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
    }

    //start thread if it's not started yet
    if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
        photoLoaderThread.start();
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;


    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;

        InputStream instream = null;   
        HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(new URI(url));   
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   

        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);   
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();   
        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);   
        try   
        {   
        instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();         
        } catch (Exception e)   
        {   

        } finally   
        {   
        if (instream != null)   
        {   
        instream.close();   
        }   
        }






        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

        Utils.CopyStream(instream, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
}

PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

public void stopThread()
{
    photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
}

//stores list of photos to download
class PhotosQueue
{
    private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();


    //removes all instances of this ImageView
    public void Clean(ImageView image)
    {
        for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
            if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                  photosToLoad.remove(j);
            else
                ++j;
        }
    }
}

class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true)
            {
                //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                        photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                    }
                if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                {
                    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                        photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();

                    }
                    Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                    cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                    Object tag=photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                    if(tag!=null && ((String)tag).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                    }
                }
                if(Thread.interrupted())
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            //allow thread to exit
        }
    }
}

PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imageView;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    //clear memory cache
    cache.clear();

    //clear SD cache
    File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
    for(File f:files)
        f.delete();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack is LIFO by nature so you probably need to:

- change Stack to LinkedList on object reference photosToLoad
- replace push() with addFirst() on photosToLoad inside the first
  synchronized block
- call getFirst() and then removeFirst() replacing pop() in the third
  synchronized block

Answer (score -1):

Please replace your ImageLoader class with this ImageLoader class. I tested the code, it's working in FIFO order.

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.add(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Queue<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new LinkedList<PhotoToLoad>();


        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
               if(photosToLoad.element().imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){

                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.poll();

                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
                        if(tag!=null && tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```